# css top tilted skew with background-image

Tags: css, border, skew

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Artz8.png)

I want to make a similar effect to this one not changing html code , using only CSS , In HTML i have got only one div with class "square" , Thank you for your support in advance .

Comment: Please put your HTML and any CSS so far into your question as a snippet. Also, could you confirm that you want the top of the image sloped - and in doing that that the image actually gets cropped? (i.e. this is not a 3D transform situation)? To make what you want clear please inlude the URL of the actual image.

Answer (score 0):

i think that is what you want

```css
.container {
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;

  -webkit-perspective: 28em;
  -moz-perspective: 28em;
  perspective: 28em;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}


.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 14em;
  height: 14em;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -7em;    
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.anim {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;    
}

.b0 {
  transform: translateX(-11.7em) rotateY(30deg) ;
}

.box img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 560px) {
  .container {
    font-size: 8px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box anim b0">
    <img src="http://www.skitzone.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/I_am_nothing__in_the_dark_by_islandtime-630x630-500x500.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Right , but i can't change anything in html code and my html code looks like :

Comment: <div class="square"></div>

Comment: @KacperRadzik you should [add your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question by editing it

Comment: I have something like this https://codepen.io/kacper1998/pen/YzeYEvo , I need help to improve a top border , a top border need to be without a white space

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is to cut the top in a sloping manner.

This snippet does this by putting the linear-gradient that is required for the border into a before pseudo element, using clip-path to get the required cutting off of the top, and putting the image as background on an after pseudo element.

```css
.square {
  width: 20vmin;
  height: 20vmin;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  position: relative;
}

.square::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a2ca3c 0%, #0a7cff 50%, #a2ca3c 100%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.square::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  --borderW: 3%;
  top: var(--borderW);
  left: var(--borderW);
  width: calc(100% - (2 * var(--borderW)));
  height: calc(100% - (2 * var(--borderW)));
  background-image: url(https://pesi.pl/img/main-bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  clip-path: polygon(var(--borderW) var(--borderW), calc(100% - var(--borderW)) calc(20% + var(--borderW)), calc(100% - var(--borderW)) calc(100% - var(--borderW)), var(--borderW) calc(100% - var(--borderW)));
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Obviously you will want to decide on exactly what width you want the border to be and whether the border is included in the overall size of the .square element (as here).